# Генерация ссылки на сброс пароля без Identity

Tags: asp.net

Пишу метод сброса пароля для пользователя, если он его забыл. Для этого нужно сгенерировать ссылку, которая будет отправлена пользователю на почту, стандартный сценарий, в общем.
Как это сделать без Identity?

Comment: *Как это сделать без Identity* - т.е.? Я так понимаю что пользователя можно идентифицировать по Identity? Не? Ну... идентифицируйте его по username. Если не то, не другое - тогда добавляйте такую инфу, по которой можно идентифицировать (от id до случайного номера, который хранится в СУБД). Если нельзя - добавляйте сверху шифрование, лучше ассиметричное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основной вариант, это таблица на сервере, где хранятся ссылки, их время жизни и связанные с ним идентификаторы пользователей. Для генерации ссылок можно использовать метод `Guid.NewGuid()`, которые гарантирует уникальность значений.

При переходе по ссылке надо убедиться, что ссылка ещё *живая* (время жизни не закончилось) и удалить запись из таблицы.

Второй вариант: использование алгоритма шифрования из тех, что встроены в .NET. Вы берёте идентификатор пользователя, и дату/время завершения действия ссылки. Сериализуете данные в массив байт, шифруете, обрабатываете алгоритмом BASE-64 и используете получившеюся строку в качестве ссылки.

Недостаток по сравнению с предыдущим методом заключается в том, что по указанной вами ссылке можно будет сгенерировать пароль несколько раз, пока не истечёт время её жизни.

Comment: Я счёл вопрос некачественным, и такой ответ может как подойти к вопросу, так и оказаться спорным.

Comment: @nick_n_a, мне показалось, что речь в вопросе идёт о том, как сгенерировать ссылку такую, чтобы она не содержала идентификатора пользователя. Я бы добавил только, что альтернативный ключ (номер телефона пользователя или его электронный адрес) тоже нельзя использовать в ссылке, иначе очень легко было бы их генерировать.